# Efficient algorithm for counting frequency of numbers in an intervals

Tags: c++, algorithm, counter, frequency, frequency-distribution

I need to build a bar gragh that illustrate a distribution of pseudorandom numbers that determined by linear congruential method

```
Xn+1 = (a * Xn + c) mod m
U = X/m
```

on the interval  [0,1]

For example:

```
Interval           Frequency     
[0;0,1]            0,05
[0,1;0,2]          0,15
[0,2;0,3]          0,1
[0,3;0,4]          0,12
[0,4;0,5]          0,1
[0,5;0,6]          0,15
[0,6;0,7]          0,05
[0,7;0,8]          0,08
[0,8;0,9]          0,16
[0,9;1,0]          0,4
```

I used such a method:

```
float mas[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
void metod1()
{
    int x=-2, m=437, a=33, c=61;
    float u;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        x=(a*x + c) % m;
        u=(float)x/(float)m;
        int r;
        r = ceil(u*10);
        mas[r] = mas[r] + 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) cout<<"["<<(float)i/10<<";"<<(float)(i+1)/10<<"]"<<" | "<<mas[i]<<"\n-----------------"<<endl;
    return;
}
```

If you know another officient methods for this problem, that are not straitforward, i would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you want to understand the algorithm? Or do you want get your desired result efficiently?

Comment: Are you actually having performance problems with this?

Comment: I need a new solution on this problem

Comment: More efficient if it is possible

Comment: I do not have any problems with this code

Comment: What's not efficient in this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently has a *much* larger problem the efficiency. Assuming you've defined `mas` as something like `int mas[10];`, it has undefined behavior.

To see the problem, let's modify your code to print out the values of `r` that it generates:

```
void metod1() {
    int mas[11] = { };
    int x = -2, m = 437, a = 33, c = 61;
    float u;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        x = (a*x + c) % m;
        u = (float)x / (float)m;
        int r;
        r = ceil(u * 10);
        //mas[r] = mas[r] + 1;
        std::cout << r << '\t';
    }
//    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout << "[" << (float)i / 10 << ";" << (float)(i + 1) / 10 << "]" << " | " << mas[i] << "\n-----------------" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Then let's look at the results:

```
0       -2      -7      -4      -7      -7      -6      0       -6      -1
-5      -6      -1      -9      -7      -2      -7      -3      0       -6
0       -8      -5      -6      -8      -6      -7      0       -2      -6
-7      -6      -2      -4      -9      0       -4      -5      -1      -2
-5      0       -2      -1      -4      -8      -5      -2      -8      -5
-9      -4      -5      -7      -9      -8      -3      -9      -9      -9
-3      -4      -5      -3      -9      -6      -5      -3      -1      0
-5      -5      -6      -7      -9      -5      -4      -1      -5      -1
-9      -2      0       -9      -6      -7      -5      -5      -3      -3
-9      -3      0       -4      -1      -1      0       -8      -4      -4
-2      -7      0       -6      -6      -8      -4      -8      -2      -8
-8      -2      -4      -7      -1      -6      -1      -3      -7      -3
-5      -9      -8      -5      -8      -7      -4      -1      -8      -7
-7      -2      -9      -5      -3      0       2       8       8       2
6       8       7       1       5       2       8       4       1       5
10      1       3       6       4       10      5       6       6       10
```

[more elided]

It doesn't *look* like you've planned for the fact that you'll be producing negative numbers, and if you fail to do so, the result is undefined behavior when you index outside the bounds of `mas`.